# what would couse uneven fuel levels in a cessna 207?

Tags: fuel-consumption

I have problems whit the level in each tank after a flight of 3 hours. I usually use the right tank the first hour and then I change to the opposite, but when I check the level after that the rigt tank seems as if have not burned the fuel.

Comment: Is your right tank fuel gauge working?

Comment: yes, it is working my friend.